# Magento 2 installation on Manjaro (Arch Linux) ~ php extension missing

Tags: php, magento2, httpd.conf, php-curl, manjaro

I am installing Magento 2 on my system and after a lot of fiddeling around, I finally got to the localhost setup wizard. The following problem occured in the readiness-check-install screen (there are a couple of  solutions online, I already tried most of them):

[image]

**ERROR:** 1 missing PHP extensions: PHP Extension curl
The important part is that I use Manjaro for this, which is an Arch Linux distro.

1: The thing is, that there is **no php-curl package** in the arch linux package store at all, I think the curl extension is already installed with php.

2: I checked my php.ini file and there is **no line** with extension=php_curl, just extension=curl.

3: **php -m** prints this:

```
php -m
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dba
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
intl
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_dblib
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
pdo_pgsql
pdo_sqlite
pgsql
Phar
phpdbg_webhelper
posix
pspell
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

4: I installed everything with brew for linux, so I can check the php package like this:

```
brew info php@7.3
php@7.3: stable 7.3.13 (bottled) [keg-only]
General-purpose scripting language
https://www.php.net/
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar/php@7.3/7.3.13 (520 files, 86.2MB)
Poured from bottle on 2020-01-10 at 10:32:22
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew-core/blob/master/Formula/php@7.3.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: httpd ✘, pkg-config ✘, xz ✔
Required: apr ✔, apr-util ✔, argon2 ✔, aspell ✔, autoconf ✔, curl-openssl ✔, freetds ✔, freetype ✔, gettext ✔, glib ✔, gmp ✔, icu4c ✔, jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, libpq ✔, libsodium ✔, libzip ✔, openldap ✔, openssl@1.1 ✔, sqlite ✔, tidy-html5 ✔, unixodbc ✔, webp ✔, bzip2 ✔, libedit ✔, libxml2 ✔, libxslt ✔, zlib ✔
==> Caveats
To enable PHP in Apache add the following to httpd.conf and restart Apache:
LoadModule php7_module /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so

<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>

Finally, check DirectoryIndex includes index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

The php.ini and php-fpm.ini file can be found in:
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/php/7.3/

php@7.3 is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew,
because this is an alternate version of another formula.

If you need to have php@7.3 first in your PATH run:
echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/php@7.3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/php@7.3/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find php@7.3 you may need to set:
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/php@7.3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/php@7.3/include"


Warning: php@7.3 provides a launchd plist which can only be used on macOS!
You can manually execute the service instead with:
php-fpm
==> Analytics
install: 75 (30 days), 96 (90 days), 96 (365 days)
install-on-request: 75 (30 days), 96 (90 days), 96 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

I really don't know how I can prevent this error.

Comment: Which version of PHP are you actually using? The one installed through package management or the one installed using brew? And have you checked whether cURL (not the cURL extension for PHP) is installed on your server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I posted the picture of the installation screen, there you can see the php version :)

Comment: What Nico is trying to say that there may be 2 php installed so check which one the magento using and according to that,check the curl extension

Comment: I have two installations of php, but the other one is version 7.4.1, which I installed with **yay**. Magento uses the 7.3.13 version, which is the one installed with brew (see above logs).

Comment: That screenshot does not answer what you've actually tried to check for all cURL requirements. Additionally, what does `php -v` tell you - maybe you've listed the modules installed for PHP 7.4?

Comment: I am really new to this, so forgive me for being such a greenhorn: How do I check, if curl is installed on my server? I looked at the phpinfo file but there is no entry for curl present? Also php -v returns **7.4.1**

Comment: The 7.3.13 version of php has the curl-openssl package installed, but there is no php-curl package available on arch linux (that was merged into php long ago, I think)

Comment: So, if `php -v` return 7.4, and your browser displays `7.3.13`, you are using different versions of PHP on cli and in the webserver. Installing cURL on your system might work the same way you installed other software, I'd assume you can use `yay` for this too

Answer (score 2):

I believe ext-curl is part of Arch's core PHP package which is why you cannot find it in pacman.  I don't *think* it is enabled by default, and you need to edit the appropriate /etc/php/php.ini file.  You are probably looking to uncomment `;extension=curl` in the php-fpm.ini.  You may need to set `extension_dir`, but this is unlikely for Arch/pacman.

I just noticed that you are using brew for linux... why?  Is this even supported by Arch? You can check the /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/etc/php/7.3/ location and see why curl is not enabled, or just use pacman.  Please note, there is a seperate ini file for the cli & fpm runtime.

Comment: Hi, I normally use pacman or yay, but for this installation, I used brew for convenience, with pacman I had to do stuff manually and brew even lists steps after the installation to get the packages to work, so I didn't have to google everything :D